# Using data inside AnyObject Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, swift2

i have i code that takes JSON data from web php file, the data goes to `data` var using `contentOfUrl` then converted to `jsonarray` var typed AnyObject using `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData`.

but the problem is when i want to use it from the `jsonarray` var i searched for tow days and i found one but didn't work because his AnyObject var structure is different.

so how can i use it?

Code:

```
    import Foundation

class DBConnectController{

    func ViewControllerConnect(DeviceID : Int) -> String{

        let data : NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL : NSURL(string: "http://xx.com/xc.php")!)!

        var jsonarray : AnyObject
        do {
            jsonarray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)

            print(jsonarray["2"]) // tried this but didn't work
            print(jsonarray["2"].value) // tried this but didn't work
            // and tried other

        } catch {
            print("Error decoding json using NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData")
        }

        return "f"
    }
}
```

`jsonarray` structure (showed when make a break point before the `return`:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is an array of dictionary objects. (BTW I'm on Xcode 6 / Swift 1.2 so you may not need the 'err' parameter there.)

(By the way, your array appears to have only one element, so check: `myStructuredData.count` before overrunning it.)

```
func viewControllerConnect(deviceID: Int) -> String? {
    var err: NSError?
    var retVal: String?
    if let url = NSURL(string: "http://xx.com/xc.php"),
        data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url), // BAD You're doing long-running network task in UI thread, address this soon
        jsonData: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments, error: &err) {
            if let myStructuredData = jsonData as? [[String: AnyObject]] { // You have an array of dictionaries there
                retVal = myStructuredData[0]["status"] as? String // For example, not sure of your exact needs & conventions
            }
            else {
                println("JSON data had unexpected structure: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        else {
            println("Could not load JSON data")
        }
    return retVal
}
```

Comment: fatal error: Array index out of range ,, i didn't get what you said about my array have one element i have 3 vars coming from json one of them is status. and thanks for remembering me to use another threats when get network data

Comment: You have a SINGLE array element. That array element is not a PRIMITIVE VALUE, rather it is an entire *dictionary*. And that dictionary has three KEY VALUE PAIRS. With the new code, use a breakpoint to explore your newly formed `myStucturedData` to find what to extract. You could assign a temp variable to `myStructuredData[0]` to make it easier. I don't know enough about it. You didn't expand the first and second keys.

Comment: worked with the change from deviceid -> 0, cause as you said i have 1 element contain the (0,1,2) 3 vars, that element is 0 :) tanks a lot

Comment: I would be concerned that your input parameter deviceID is no longer involved. Depends on what stage of development you're at.

Comment: yup, it still forward ahead, ill change some thing in you answer so its worked with people using swift 2 like the Q title is

Answer (score 0):

The Swift 2 rendition of the answer is as follows:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { data, response, error in
    guard data != nil else {
        print("dataTaskWithURL error: \(error)")
        return
    }

    do {
        if let jsonarray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [[String: AnyObject]],
            let status = jsonarray.first?["status"] as? String {
                // use `status` here
                print(status)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error decoding json using NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData: \(error)")
    }
}
task.resume()
```

This:

- Uses asynchronous request rather than synchronous `NSData(contentsOfURL:)` ... never use synchronous network calls from the main thread of the app;
- Guards against network errors (rather than forced unwrapping with `!` which would crash if there was some unpreventable network error);
- Gracefully unwrap `jsonarray` and `status` rather than forced unwrapping;
- Log the JSON parsing error if any; and
- Use `.first` with optional chaining rather than `[0]`, because the latter can crash if you get empty array and you end up exceeding the bounds of the array.